# displays errors like there is content

Tags: jquery, html

This is how I am in the process of building a status page like facebook just in a slightly different way.

When I tell it that it should be it on the page you will see it just forward of error text matter if it says something or does not.

Jquery code her:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var form = $('.form'),
        required = form.find('.required'),
        button = form.find('.statusBox');

    button.on('click', function(e) {
        var container = $(this).parent(),
            status = true;

        container.find('.input').each(function() {
        var input = $(this),
            section = input.parent(),
            value = input.val(),
            error = section.find('.fejlError');

            error.hide();

            if(value.length <= 0) {
                error.fadeIn();
                status = false;
                setTimeout(function() {
                        error.fadeOut();
                }, 8000);
            }
        });

        return status;
    });
});
</script>
```

html code here:

```
<div class="tekstStatus form">
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">
    <form name="loginOK" action="#" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li class="section">
                <div class="fejlError">Error come her!!</div>
                <textarea name="tekst" class="input" cols="75" rows="7"></textarea>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Slå op" class="statusBox">
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I click the submit button so if I have nothing written in text content will see it, well, it must be so too.
However, if I have written something in the content of the text BOX so, it also forward no matter what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the issue, you're missing `e.preventDefault()`. 
See working example http://jsfiddle.net/tsfCp/

Comment: Where are the error showing? In the fiddle example, there are no errors. The correction made was just to stop event bubbling, because the code you posted isn't jQuery efficient. Probably it doesn't have the functionality you wish.